# omniauth gem and routes generated automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, omniauth

when I am including `omniauth` (or any omniauth provider) I do not see the routes. Where do I know which route is supported and how can I enforce that all routes are listed in the `routes.rb`

Comment: Omniauth doesn't actually contain any routes, controller or views - its more of a kit that you use to build your own authentication solution then a plug and play solution like Devise.

Answer (score -1):

Type in your terminal

> rails routes

It list every generated routes